# Illustrator CC Linux doesn't display interface after opened

Tags: wine, flash, process, adobe

Some time ago I have downloaded through this link an Adobe Illustrator CC adaptation to run on Linux environment: https://github.com/Gictorbit/illustratorCClinux and followed these steps until a day before yesterday it was running normally, but yesterday I have faced an issue each time that I clicked at the New Button to create a new document, the program created a new document but after the application closed automatically.

After that, I have reinstalled the application and executed it again, but for my surprise the application displayed an alert at the upper corner saying "Adobe Illustrator CC launched, and Adobe Illustrator CC is ready", even so, the application doesn't open in my environment in any way.

Unfortunately, I don't have any idea in how to proceed now, I have tried several reinstallations, I already reinstalled Wine, cleaned old cache and nothing worked.

After I have verified which processes are running but Illustrator didn't appear there.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa, I would like to move to Windows after that but but Ubuntu is very important to me and I would rather to use Illustrator to create the figures to the research papers now I am stucked.

Comment: The [wine database](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=20) indicates that Illustrator 25.1.0.90 runs OK - the version you got from gitlab does not state the version of illustrator, and is perhaps not licensed?  I not also that the github has not been updated in a while.

Comment: So I don't know what happened, in fact, this GitHub Illustrator version that was optimized to run in Ubuntu with Wine was running normally until last Saturday, at Saturday it was possible to create a New File and set the paper format when the page was opened it immediately closed out of the blue and after I decided to reinstall it but even the application didn't open, I already still thinking to format my whole OS but I don't know if there is any another alternative to fix it.